# What code is generated when "Add New Item" is chosen and "Component Class" is selected in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

The reason I am asking is that **Visual Studio Express** is missing this item when choosing "Add new Item".

Because of that I would like to create it by hand but I do not know what code to add.

I would really appriciate if someone with professional or higher editions would paste the C# code that is generated when adding "Component Class"

**SOLUTION**

Use the code in the answer but to obtain visual part of the component, the user control has to be created and not just a regular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code part

Component1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace blabla
{
    public partial class Component1 : Component
    {
        public Component1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Component1(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Component1.Designer.cs

```
namespace blabla
{
    partial class Component1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

But there's a visual part that you will miss...